# How can I add the servicenetworking.services.addPeering privilege to an user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a Cloud SQL instance using private IPs, which have [recently](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/introducing-private-networking-connection-for-cloud-sql) become available. It seems I need the `servicenetworking.services.addPeering` privilege, but I can't find it neither in the roles nor in the APIs.

Is it hidden somewhere else? How can I add this privilege for an user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission "servicenetworking.services.addPeering" is included in the role "compute.NetworkAdmin", even if it the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) doesn't list it.

If you want to add it to a custom role it isn't working properly yet, even when you can add via CLI, as it isn't specified yet which permissions beside that one you need to be able to create the instance.

Comment: Actual role is "compute.networkAdmin". Sorry to be pedantic, but cli is case sensite and edit has to be at least for 6 chars.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to enable for setting up a cloudsql :

```
- Enable Google api=  Service Networking API (This is for the project)
- You/email ID logged in creating CloudSQL instacne should have Computer Network Admin.
```

That it.

**CLI:**
*Enalbe API for your project:*

```
gcloud services enable servicenetworking.googleapis.com --project=your-project-name-here
```

Elevate Your privilege to Network Admin:

```
> -Login to google console : console.cloud.google.com
> -Go to IAM
> -Search your logged in email ID and add a Role: "Network Admin"
```

thats it.

Atfer that you will be able to enable private IP  for cloudSQL.